# Intel AC-Adapter causes system-stuttering

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, acer-aspire

I have a Acer Aspire laptop (about 4 years old) with an Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 as my WLAN-Adapter. Also Windows 10 runs as the OS. Now my problem is that my sound, mouse and video stutters (mostly the sound) when my computer loads data from the Internet (e.g. visiting websites or even background activity).
The driver should be the most recent version (August 2019).
I have absolutely no idea what causes this behaviour; particularly because it started not more than a week ago.

I hope someone will know an answer.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had sound stuttering on my Lenovo Desktop and it was (after some time) the Audio driver updated by Lenovo. Update Video, Chipset and Audio drivers and see if that helps

Comment: I've updated the sound-driver (WLAN-driver was up to date).
Now it do not stutter any more, but I think it can happen again, because the stuttering vanished temporally after the WLAN-driver update.

Do you know by chance where to download the latest WAN Miniport drivers, because they are the only ones where I can not find updates (my are from 2006).

Comment: I think updating the Audio may be the solution for you. For WAN Miniport Drivers, update those in Device Manager. Open Device Manager, expand the network section, right click on Miniport and select Update Driver. Do that for all. But there may not be updates there as they are stable devices

Comment: I tried this and the Device Manager can not find anything new.
Ironically after I restarted my PC Windows Update reinstalled the Audio-Driver to the old version.
I just hope Windows know what it does ...